# STUnion an entire column in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, postgis, jooq

I'd like to apply the PostGIS ST_Union operation on all Geometries in a column. The equivalent SQL would look something like this:

```
select ST_Union(region) from region_geometries
    where ST_Contains(point);
```

However, kOOQs implementation of `stUnion` takes two arguments, so I'm not sure how to utilize it. https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/spatial-functions/st-union-function/

Sample code that doesn't compile but looks like what I want to do:

```kotlin
val result = context
    .select(stUnion(
        region_geometries.REGION.cast(Geometry::class.java)
    ))
    .from(region_geometries)
    .where(
        stContains(
            region_geometries.REGION.cast(Geometry::class.java),
            geometryPointConverter.toGeometry(point),
        ),
    )
    .fetch()
```

Is my best option here to construct the raw SQL for `ST_Union` instead of utilizing jOOQs `stUnion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.18, there is yet little support for spatial aggregate functions, see [#12736](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12736). The [`stUnion()` function taking two arguments](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/spatial-functions/st-union-function/) is not an aggregate function.

You can use the generic [`DSL.aggregate()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#aggregate(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType,org.jooq.Field...)) function as a workaround:

```java
aggregate("ST_Union", SQLDataType.GEOMETRY, region_geometries.REGION)
```

Or just use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), which is the raw SQL escape hatch for arbitrary expressions:

```java
field("ST_Union({0})", SQLDataType.GEOMETRY, region_geometries.REGION)
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! `aggregate` is exactly what I need.